# What is the identity gained after these manipulations?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

### Background

Consider the following divergent integral:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-e^x} e^{ax} x^b dx $$

Where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers such that $b > a$. Multipling $e^{-x} \cdot e^x$ inside the integral.

$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-e^x} e^x e^{(a-1)x} x^b dx $$

Using integration by parts and noticing $(e^{-e^x})' = -e^{-e^x}e^x $:

$$ \implies - \int_{-\infty}^\infty (e^{-e^x})'  e^{(a-1)x} x^b dx  =  - \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-e^x}  (e^{(a-1)x} x^b)' dx  $$

Again multiplying $e^{-x} \cdot e^x$ inside the integral and repeating the process:

$$  = - \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-e^x}  e^x \cdot e^{-x}(e^{(a-1)x} x^b)' dx  $$

$$ =   \int_{-\infty}^\infty (e^{-e^x})'\cdot e^{-x}(e^{(a-1)x} x^b)' dx  $$

$$  =   \int_{-\infty}^\infty (e^{-e^x})\cdot (e^{-x}(e^{(a-1)x} x^b)')' dx  $$

This trick will only work $a$ times. The leading order term in $x$ will be something like: $ a!\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-e^x} x^b dx  $

My idea was to take:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\int_{-n}^n e^{-e^x} e^{ax} x^b dx + (-1)^a (a-1)! \int_{-n}^n e^{-e^x} x^b dx}{\int_{-n}^n e^{-e^x} x^{b-1} dx} $$

Now one can use two ways two solve this:

The first by using L'hopital rule and differentiating. The other is by using integration by parts. I've tried to do this myself but I've got disagreement between my answers (I think I'm messing up the calculation).

### Question

Is my idea correct? What is the identity gained after these manipulations? Furthermore, what is the identity of gained after the $x^{k}$ coefficient using limits and integration by parts? for:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\int_{-n}^n e^{-e^x} e^{ax} x^b dx + (-1)^a (a-1)! \int_{-n}^n e^{-e^x} x^b dx}{\int_{-n}^n e^{-e^x} x^{b-1} dx} = ?$$

Comment: Why do you say the integral is divergent?

Comment: @JuliánAguirre after repeated integration by parts one will be left with something like: $e^{-e^x} x^b$ as shown in the background this diverges for $- \infty$

Comment: The integral is convergent. When $x\to+\infty$ it is dominated by $e^{-e^x}$; when $x\to-\infty$ by $e^{ax}$. May be you did not consider the boundary terms in one of the integration by parts.

Comment: As Julián Aguirre commented, not only they are convergent but they have very nice expressions.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici can u please comment the expression?